# Why this error pops up when running a docker-compose service of postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

When I try running my docker compose application and specifically my postgresql service it gives me this error:

**"psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory. Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?"**

I tried adding a postgresql.conf file and mount it on the host machine like this:
'./postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf'

This is the service definition:

```
db:
  image: postgres:15.2-alpine
  container_name: postgresql
  restart: on-failure
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: "${DB_USER}"
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASS}"
    POSTGRES_DB: "${DB_NAME}"
  volumes:
    - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    - ./postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

The contents of the configuration file:

```
listen_addresses = '*'

unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432'
```

What could be the problem to this error? I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and there seems to be something else I might be missing.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the postgres service definition from your docker-compose file (without the config changes)

Comment: When I try to to run it, it works as it should. In the logs from the container, am I right that it's when it's running the init.sql script that it fails?

Comment: Yeah, apparently there were some commands that caused this error to pop up, I changed something and it worked. thank you!

Comment: You show a psql error, but you don't show anything that would be running psql.